# nextjs axios requests inside getServerSideProps always return 404 after deployment with nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, axios, next.js

I have nextjs app running on ec2 instance with nodejs backend

When the app makes an axios request inside `useEffect` it works perfectly, but when the app sends a request from inside `getServersideProps` function it fails with 404 status code and the request does not arrive to backend at all.

This is the nginx file

```
server {
server_name frontend.domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

    # we need to remove this 404 handling
    # because of Next's error handling and _next folder
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

```
server {
    server_name api.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is the axios configuration:

```
    const configModified = {
  baseURL: 'https://api.domain.com',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers:{},
  adapter: cache.adapter
  // global customizations
}
    export const request = (request) => {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
  return {
    request: axios({ ...configModified, ...request}, cancelToken: source.token }),
    source
  }
}
```

it is working on localhost as expected but after deployment the requests fails only in `getServerSideProps` function

Comment: getServerSideProps is a function that gets executed on the nodejs server .. if you deploy the app as static via nginx, you are no longer using the nodejs server to render your application .. it works in dev mode because the dev setup serves the app over nodejs

Comment: I have deployed the app with server not as static site and `getServerSideProps` function always called and the issue is not the function itself but in the http requests inside it.

Comment: In the prod environment, have you consoled out the request and placed it via postman to check if a 404 is returned ? i.e ```  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
  return {
    request: axios({ ...configModified, ...request}, cancelToken: source.token }),
    source
  }``` - What is the source was constructed outside of the app, does it still fail?

Comment: Are you sure port of ur backend is still 3000?

Comment: @JSEvgeny  the backend is working, but not from server side requests

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your axios instance based on you are on the server or client.

```
export default ({ req }) => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    // We are on the server
    return axios.create({
      baseURL:
        "http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local",
      headers: req.headers,
    });
  } else {
    // We must be on the browser
    return axios.create({
      baseUrl: "https://api.domain.com",
      // if it causes error
      //   baseUrl: "/"
    });
  }
};
```

then when you are on server, pass the context object

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const client = buildClient(context);
  ...
};
```

Comment: It is already working as it, in server side locally, no need to modify it

Comment: What does this `baseURL` mean in serverside ? 
`http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @GhyathDarwish what is https://api.domain.com